# Ugly MathJax alignment on Zoomed pages (possibly Chrome specific)

Tags: bug, mathjax

I just noticed in passing that MathJax alignment in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253537/242)  has become very ugly - see the excerpt below. The string of $x$'s is wavering up and down. I don't recall seeing this when the answer was composed. MathJax 2.7.0, Chrome v54.0.2840.59 — woff or otf fonts, Win7 Pro 64b. The problem does not occur in the latest version of FireFox in the same environment, so it may be Chrome specific.

**Update** Another datapoint: my Zoom was at 90% in Chrome, so the bug may depend on that (reproduced by DanielR at 90% and 125% Zoom - see comments). At 100% Zoom there is no problem. FireFox looks ok at all zoom levels.

[image]

Comment: No repro. Seems to be your browser (or maybe it's the font's fault).

Comment: @DanielFischer It may well depend on the fonts and/or MathJax config - which hasn't changed on my end since the answer was composed.

Comment: Also no reproduction, using Chrome on 64-bit Windows 7 with Common HTML as my Math Renderer setting.

Comment: It's aligned for me whether I use HTML-CSS, Common-HTML, or SVG as the renderer, so the problem seems to be on your end. Chrome is my first suspect.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it may be specific to Chrome since I just verified that it doesn't occur in the latest version of FireFox.

Comment: I have the same behavior at 90 % zoom in Chrome. A similar thing happens also at 125 %.

Comment: @DanielR Thanks for the confirmation (and thanks to others who also tested).

Comment: This might be https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1498, due to a bug in WebKit/Safari and Blink/Chrome.