# MathJax squashed my Chinese $\rm{\small T}heorem$

Tags: bug, mathjax

The letter T in CRT is too small below (source [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3220043/242)). This is the only letter in the alphabet that exhibits this problem in that context. Alas, it renders so ugly that I've been forced to resort to alternatives such as the [$\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) (just kidding, but it is a bit hard on my eyes).

[image]
Platform: Chrome 74.0.3729.131 on Win7 at 100% zoom.

Comment: Looks fine on my computer (Arch Linux, Chromium)

Comment: I just recalled this [old post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25250/242) which may be related.

Comment: Does it look any better for you if you use `\text{CRT}` rather than `{\rm CRT}`?  Also, what output renderer are you using?

Comment: @DavideCervone Alas, that doesn't help. It goes away at $110\%$ zoom, but it is still there all other neighboring zoom values $75,80,90,100,125,150,175\%\ \ \ $

Comment: @Davide I'm using the default MathJax settings, renderer = HTML-CSS,  MathJax.js v2.7.5
TeX Input Jax v2.7.5
HTML-CSS Output Jax v2.7.5
PreviewHTML Output Jax v2.7.5
mml Element Jax v2.7.5

Comment: @BillDubuque, is it any better if you switch to CommonHTML?  I assume SVG would not show this artifact.

Comment: Also, thanks for trying out `\text`.

Comment: @Davide Right, no problem with SVG. With CommonHTML it is bad at 80,90% and good at 75,100.110,125%.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I suspect that the issue is that the MathJax fonts are not well hinted.  I'm not a font expert, but in my experience, font hinting has always been much more critical in Windows, and the results, especially at small sizes, have typically been poorer there.  It looks the top of the T may be one pixel low, probably due to a difference in rounding.  Both the outlines themselves, and the hinting, were algorithmically generated, and that leads to some variation in the control point positions from letter to letter, and so to potential rounding problems.

Comment: You might try switching to the STIX fonts or one of the other web fonts to see if there is a difference (in HTML-CSS -- they aren't available in CommonHTML).  Try entering `MathJax.Menu.showFontMenu(true)` in the browser console windows that should make an extra menu available in the MathJax contextual menu.  Choose `STIX (Web)` in the font submenu of the math setting menu and see if that helps (it will reload the page in order to make the change).

Comment: @Davide If I change the defaults then I would no longer see how my posts render for the majority of readers (who presumably use the defaults).

Comment: @BillDubuque, actually a number of people will be getting STIX fonts automatically from HTML-CSS output.  Those who have STIX installed locally (and idon'thave MathJax fonts installed locally) will have output using STIX.  For example, Xander's screen snapshot appears to be using the STIX fonts.  So switching to STIX it not necessarily bad, and does represent what a number of people will see.

Comment: I see the same thing that @BillDubuque sees; I'm on a Windows 10 PC using Chrome. As far as I'm aware, everything is at the default setting.

Comment: @Davide What are the current defaults for renderer and fonts? Are they context dependent?

Comment: @Davide To fix the font hints for the T where should I look? (a long time ago I worked on font hinting for Bitstream).

Comment: @BillDubuque, SE uses HTML-CSS by default (unless you change it with the  menu).  That renderer chooses either the MathJax TeX fonts or the STIX fonts, depending on what is installed locally on your computer (and defaults to MathJax TeX web fonts if neither is available locally).  The font hints are in the fonts themselves, so you would need to download them and add better hints to the font files.  You could install those locally to get the modified versions.

Comment: @Davide Thanks, but the goal is to fix it for everybody, not just locally. What method  can I tell users to employ to determine the fonts that MathJax is currently using?

Comment: @BillDubuque, making fixes for everyone would require fixing the fonts and making a pull request to the MathJax github repository that was reviewed and accepted into the project.  To determine the fonts in use, select the "About MathJax" option in the MathJax contextual menu.  The font used should be listed just under the MathJax version number at the top of the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, all my tests above used the "web TeX fonts".  I've added an entry to my TODO list for the font hint fix, but, alas, its a few hundred items from the top of the queue. Maybe someday....

Comment: @BillDubuque, no problem.  I understand about the to-do list.  It's on mine as well, but even after 10 years of MathJax, it hasn't been done...

Comment: @Davide I've got some on my list over a couple decades old. so I can relate to that. Maybe someone else will volunteer with the exposure given here. Thanks for all the superb work on MathJax. No doubt there are much less trivial things on your MathJax todo list so apologies for bothering you about something so minor.

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you for your kind words.  We are working hard on v3.0, which should be out in the very near future.  The fonts need an overhaul, and that is planned, not for v3.0, but for v3.1, so I probably will get to that sooner rather than later.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathjax-plugin-for-github/ioemnmodlmafdkllaclgeombjnmnbima?hl=en ?

Answer (score 6):

(Posted as an answer, as comments don't support images)

This seems to be a problem with whatever software you are using.  Under Opera version 58.0.3135.132 (under Mac OS), I see the following:

[image]

Perhaps you could specify the browser you are using?

Comment: What level Zoom are you using?

Comment: @BillDubuque Whatever the default is.  It looks fine under Chrome and Safari, too.  Again, it would be helpful to know what *your* configuration is, as it would appear that neither Asaf nor I see what you are seeing.

Comment: It is now in the OP. Thanks for checking on your platform.

Answer (score 5):

On a $64$-bit Win$7$ computer, accessed through a remote terminal connection, using FireFox $66.0.5$, I can reproduce the problem, but only at $100$% zoom. At $90$% or $110$%, it looks fine. However, on the same machine, using the same version of Chrome $74.0.3729.131$ as you have, the problem doesn't occur at $110$%, $100$%, $90$% and $67$% zoom, but it does happen at $80$% & $75$% zoom. On a $64$-bit Windows $10$ machine, with a $1280$x$1024$ resolution, using Microsoft Edge version $44.17763.1.0$, the problem occurs at all zoom levels I tried, i.e., $50$%, $75$%, $100$%, $125$% and $150$% (but it seems to be minimal for the $125$% & $150$% zoom).

If need be, I can try different OS's & browsers, but I believe what I've described above shows there is no simple pattern and, perhaps, no simple solution. Overall, I suspect it depends on various factors, including the fonts being used, the screen resolution, the MathJax renderer, the browser, the OS, etc.

Comment: Yes, it probably depends on motley factors and is likely related to the [$x$-waves bug](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25250/242) I reported a few years ago. If only it didn't occur on such a frequently used term. Thanks for the troubleshooting help.

Comment: @BillDubuque You are welcome for the troubleshooting help. My biggest display issue is with how numeric digits are shown by default. To avoid that, I usually show them inside MathJax statements instead. For me, it's still not completely correct, but it's noticeably better.

Answer (score 0):

$$\overset{C\hspace{-2px}R\style{zoom:1.1}{T}}{\iff}$$

> \overset{C\hspace{-3px}R\style{zoom:1.1}{T}}{\iff}

Works in my browser currently ( with htmlcss or SVG renderer, all of common html,preview html makes the T bigger) but seems a little annoying to type out. chrome version 76 something at my local library.

Comment: I was on a desktop, but on mobile ( beta browser) now the t looks too big.

Comment: Here the T looks too small.

Comment: is it any bigger than the original ?

Comment: It looks smaller than the C and the R; it looks mostly like in screen shot in OP.

Comment: At zoom 90% and 110% the look the same size, the CRT I mean. I did not yet find one where the T looks larger.

Comment: $$\stackrel{CRT}{\iff}$$

Comment: The comment looks good to me.

Comment: uses stackrel instead of overset. an equivalent mentioned in the LaTeX wikibook.

Comment: only difference I can spot in developer mode is that one uses italics versions the other doesn't seem to.